# Passing function to navigationOptions and check if it's ready?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm passing a function to my header via useLayoutEffect

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setParams({
      toggleFavoriteHandler
    });
  }, [toggleFavoriteHandler]);
```

I get it in navigationOptions of the screen:

```
const toggleFavorite = navigationData.navigation.getParam(
  "toggleFavoriteHandler"
);
console.log(toggleFavorite);
```

The console.log gives me:

undefined

[Function anonymous]

[Function anonymous]

So the function is only defined after a few milliseconds. When I press the buttion with the function too early, my app crashes.
Is there any way to check if the function is ready?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    onSelect={() => {
            if (typeof toggleFavorite === "function") {
              toggleFavorite();
            }
          }}
```

Not sure if it's the correct way to do it but at least it prevents the app from crashing. Not sure why nobody could help me, though.